# PHP, Ajax login form issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am developing php login form using ajax control, actually I am new to this concept. I have index.php from there, I am sending username and password through ajax method. Ajax function will call ajaxAdminLogin.php, After doing user verification process it is not redirecting to dashboard.php. Here is my code please help me

**index.php**

```
<body>
    <div class="loginbg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row content-area">
                <div class="col-md-6 company-profile">
                    <div id="" class="adminLoginText">
                        <h1>Admin Login</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id="" class="comapny-text">                            
                        <h3>Uni Web Tech</h3>
                        <p>Website Designing & Development</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 login-form">
                    <div id="" class="login-form-area">
                        <form method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="admin-username">User Name</label>
                                <input id="admin-username" class="form-control" type="text" name="adminUsername" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="admin-password">Password</label>
                                <input id="admin-password" class="form-control" type="password" name="adminPassword" required>
                            </div>                              
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="adminLogin" id="adminLogin">Login</button>
                        </form>
                        <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                        <p style="margin-top:30px;text-align:center;color:#ea6957;" id="login-error"></p>
                    </div>                      
                </div>                  
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</body> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/adminloginJs.js"></script>
```

**adminloginJs.js**

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $("#adminLogin").click(function () {
            var adminUsername = $("#admin-username").val().trim();
            var adminPassword = $("#admin-password").val().trim();

            if (adminUsername != "" && adminPassword != "")
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "ajax/ajaxAdminLogin.php?adminUsername=" + adminUsername + "&adminPassword=" + adminPassword,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (message) {
                        $("#login-error").text("");
                        $("#login-error").text(message);
                        if ($("#login-error").text().trim() == "Done") {
                            window.location.href = "http://localhost/unidashboard/dashboard.php";
                        }
                    }
                });

                /*$.post("ajaxAdminLogin.php",{adminUsername: adminUsername, adminPassword: adminPassword})
                 .done(function(data){
                 if(data.trim() == "Done"){
                 window.location = "dashboard.php";
                 }
                 else{
                 $("#login-error").text(data);
                 }
                 });*/
            } else
            {
                $("#login-error").text("");
                $("#login-error").text("Please enter Username and Password");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**ajaxAdminLogin.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
/* Uni Web Tech Online Exam DB Connection */
include("includes/dbConnection.php");
/* Tracking User IP Address */

function get_ip_address() {
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
                $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false) {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$AdminIPAddress = get_ip_address();

$username = $_POST['adminUsername'];
$password = $_POST['adminPassword'];
/* Fetching User Data */
$LoginSql = "select AdminId, Email, Password, Role, Status from adminusers where AdminId =  '$username' or Email = '$username'";
$result = $uni_DB_Con->query($LoginSql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // fetching user details
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //verifying Enabled or Disabled
        if ($row['Status'] == "Enable") {
            // verifying username
            if ($row['AdminId'] == $username || $row['Email'] == $username) {
                if ($row['Password'] == $password) {
                    $AdminId = $row['AdminId'];

                    /* updating user login status 0 to 1 in users table */
                    $loginStatusSql = "UPDATE adminusers SET LoginStatus=1 WHERE AdminId = '$AdminId'";
                    $uni_DB_Con->query($loginStatusSql);

                    /* Creating session */
                    $_SESSION["AdminId"] = $AdminId;
                    $_SESSION["Role"] = $row['Role'];

                    /* Details for Activity */
                    $Login = Date("d - F - Y H:i:s");
                    $loginActivitySql = "INSERT INTO admin_activity(AdminId, AdminIPAddress, Login, Logout) VALUES ('$AdminId','$AdminIPAddress','$Login','0')";

                    $uni_DB_Con->query($loginActivitySql);


                    /* After storing login date and time navigating to dashboard page */
                    echo "Done"; /* redirect done from adminlogin.js */
                } else {
                    echo "Invalid Password.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Invalid Username.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, You are disabled. Please contact admin.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

please tell me, If I did any mistake.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection. **Never** store passwords as plain text

Comment: Quote from [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293931/should-one-answer-terribly-poor-questions/293946#293946): *We do not want debug-my-wall-of-code-for-me questions. Period. [...]* such questions are likely to get downvoted, closed and/or deleted. Try to reduce your code to a specific problem you've got by creating [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the success function in your ajax that returns the message is having problem.. change your php code to return 1 or 0 as sucessful or unsuccessfull. and in ajax just check if message=0 or 1 redirect or do whatever. note your code is prone to sql injection

Comment: why not just do `if (message== "Done") {
                            window.location.href = "http://localhost/unidashboard/dashboard.php";
                        }`? Also, what are the errors? Try to add an else statement there to print the content of `message`

Comment: @hungrykoala I did same thing but no use. Actually everything is done well but page is not redirecting automatically.

Comment: @nani0077 do a `console.log(message)` inside you if and else statement and tell us what they printed

Comment: So, what does it actually return? Tried `console.log(message);`? Checked the console for potential errors? Checked the network tab under developer tools to see what the request actually returns? Basically, have you done any basic debugging? You need to pin down _where_ it breaks.

Comment: if your doing redirect after the ajax then you don't need ajax

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, When i double click the login button it is navigating but two login are stored in db

Comment: @madalinivascu, then how

Comment: @madalinivascu Why not? If it fails, the OP probably don't want to redirect the user or reload the page if the auth fails.

Comment: That doesn't really help. You need to debug your code. Check what `message` contains (using console.log() as we already suggested) and/or check the network tab.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check The Commented part** in the script below maybe its casue your passing a query stirng and your using a post in the server to pick up the data

```
       <script>
                    $("document").ready(function () {
                        $("#adminLogin").click(function () {
                            var adminUsername = $("#admin-username").val().trim();
                            var adminPassword = $("#admin-password").val().trim();

                            if (adminUsername != "" && adminPassword != "")
                            {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
////From Here Replace and add these /////

url: "ajax/ajaxAdminLogin.php,
    data:{'adminusername':adminUsername,'adminPassword':adminPassword}
         dataType: 'HTML',

//////////////////////////////////////

                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function (message) {
        console.log(message)
                                        $("#login-error").text("");
                                        $("#login-error").text(message);
                                        if ($("#login-error").text().trim() == "Done") {
                                            window.location.href = "http://localhost/unidashboard/dashboard.php";
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                /*$.post("ajaxAdminLogin.php",{adminUsername: adminUsername, adminPassword: adminPassword})
                                 .done(function(data){
                                 if(data.trim() == "Done"){
                                 window.location = "dashboard.php";
                                 }
                                 else{
                                 $("#login-error").text(data);
                                 }
                                 });*/
                            } else
                            {
                                $("#login-error").text("");
                                $("#login-error").text("Please enter Username and Password");
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: also use the console.log(message) to check what your server is returning

Comment: console.log(message) nothing

Comment: ok comment out the code in php and just type `echo $_POST['adminUsername'];`

Comment: comment out everything else

Comment: also did you add the   new url/data/datatype properies i mentioned above?

Comment: ok comment out all the other code in your success function and then just use console.loh(message)

Comment: in your code you didn't closed at end of ajax/ajaxAdminLogin.php

Comment: also you dont have to do ` $("#login-error").text("");
                                        $("#login-error").text(message);`   you can directly do  $("#login-error").text(message);

Comment: Yes, I commented all and it shown USERNAME, I got response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156802/discussion-between-reuben-gomes-and-nani0077).

Comment: console.log(message); this is not displaying any thing